# How to list McNair Scholarship research on resume?

Tags: resume

My husband received a McNair Scholarship; part of the benefit to the program is what they call a "[Summer Research Institute](http://mcnair.usc.edu/prospective/sri.html)", a program under which he was given funds to design and carry out research under the eye of a faculty member which culminated in a publication. We're composing his CV, and while we listed the publication under his publications section, does the SRI count as job experience? He's looking to apply to research positions, so it seems relevant, but I'm not sure how to word it since it's not a traditional internship or anything like that. What job title would that even be?

From their website:

> In summary, Scholars experience the following during the SRI:
>
> -Independent research
>
> -Research Methods Workshops
>
> -Academic/Scholarly Writing Seminars
>
> -Communication/Presentation Workshops
>
> -Resume/CV Development Sessions
>
> -GRE Preparation
>
> -Special Faculty Presentations
>
> -Special Graduate Student Presentations
>
> -Special McNair Alumni Presentation
>
> -Graduate School Preparation Workshops
>
> -Development of a Graduate School Application Plan
>
> -Cultural Awareness Activities & Educational Field Trips
>
> -Summer-end Research Symposium where students present their research before an audience comprised of USC students, staff, faculty, & other
>   McNair Programs
>
> -Complete a final Research Paper and PowerPoint Presentation
>
> -Students awarded a $2800 stipend and are eligible for program-sponsored housing scholarships

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this Research Institute is job experience.

If you're writing an academic CV, you need to consult an academic adviser to determine the best way to describe this experience.

If you're writing a commercial / industrial resume, you should write something like this

```
Summer 2014  McNair Scholarship Summer Research Institute. Under the
             supervision of Prof. Albert Einstein, I worked with a small 
             team to confirm theoretical predictions of reality distortion
             field strengths when Steve Jobs and Bill Gates give keynote
             addresses at conferences.
```

or whatever is true.

Answer (score 0):

Since your husband is looking for a research position, his CV should include a PUBLICATIONS section. This is my suggestion:

**ACADEMIC AWARDS AND PUBLICATIONS**

McNair Scholar (Summer 2014)

[Title of published article], by [Authors including your husband]. Editor:[], Year:[], pp. [](*)

(*) NB: this article was published in partial fulfillment of the requirements for successful completion of the McNair Scholars Program, offered by the University of Southern California's Summer Research Institute.

Whatever other requirements that your husband fulfilled as part of his participation in the McNair Scholars program, he can cite them as part of his cover letters. Frankly, the only part of the Program that a prospective academic employer would be interested in is that your husband received hands-on training in independent research.

Comment: I mentioned that we put the publication in the publications section, but I'm more looking to document that he got research experience, training, and practice designing a research project

Comment: @Yamikuronue He'll be mentioning that in any of his cover letters.